# joining 3 different colums including null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 3 tables table1 has the column id1 with three values in it '1','2','3' and table2 has column id2 with three values '3','4','5' and table3 has column id3 with three values '5','6','7'  how do i join all the three tables, and i also want the null value to be displayed.pls go through the example below.

```
table1               table2              table3

 id1                  id2                  id3
  1                    3                    5
  2                    4                    6
  3                    5                    7
```

the output which i expect is

```
id1     id2     id3
 1     null    null
 2     null    null
 3       3     null
null     4     null
null     5      5
null   null     6
null   null     7
```

some1 pls do help me am confused